# How to prevent Huge Aggregate Queries from crashing MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have a MongoDB instance where sometimes previously unexpected queries need to be made. (That's the whole point of schema-less, right?)

Some of these are very complex and therefore take a long time. This is fine with me, but what I'm struggling with is these queries crashing Mongod service itself.

I would think a natural way to handle these cases would be simply timeout or reject the query, but looks like Mongod just crashes (The kernel kills mongod process with OOM error)

This is frustrating because this comes without warning. I am aware that MongoDB leaves memory management to the OS, so i'm confused why it allows this type of crashes to happen.

Is there an easy way to deal with this type of situation?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with MongoDB. What you have is an OOMkill, which means that the provisioned hardware is 1) don't have enough RAM for the work you're asking it to do, and/or 2) don't have swap configured. Note that OOMkill is an OS function. MongoDB cannot timeout or reject the query, and it is not "crashing". It was forcibly killed because the server ran out of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. [cursor.maxTimeMS()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/) allows you to set a timeout for the query. If a specified time passes, the query will be terminated.

## From the documentation

MongoDB targets operations for termination if the associated cursor exceeds its allotted time limit. MongoDB terminates operations that exceed their allotted time limit using the same mechanism as db.killOp(). MongoDB only terminates an operation at one of its designated interrupt points.

MongoDB does not count network latency between the client and the server towards a cursor’s time limit. For a sharded cluster, however, MongoDB does include the latency between the mongos and mongod instances towards this time limit.

Queries that generate multiple batches of results continue to return batches until the cursor exceeds its allotted time limit.

### Usage

```
db.collection.find({description: /August [0-9]+, 1969/}).maxTimeMS(50)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Would this effectively help with the memory issue I am suffering from? I just want to make sure long running queries don't end up crashing mongod, and I think it would if the timeout effectively cancels the ongoing query after timeout and clears from memory, but if it doesn't we'll still have the same problem.

Comment: @Vlad If the kernel is killing mongod, you can limit mongod's memory usage with cgroup or set [max memory limit for wiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB)

Comment: Please note that while this may help to limit the running time of a query, it won't help with the memory usage of the query itself. On another note, limiting the size of the WiredTiger cache won't change the total memory used by the `mongod` process. I believe the workload just needs more RAM than what the server has, and so the kernel ran out of memory and just kill the largest user of memory, which will always be `mongod`. The best solution is to provision more RAM and sufficient swap space.